# Gave a wrong ID number for a Spanish railway (Refne, AVE) ticket. How likely is this cause an issue?

Tags: trains, spain, identity-cards

I'm travelling by train in Spain this weekend as an EU citizen. I reserved and paid for an AVE ticket online. I gave my ID card number as the number of travel document. However, it seems there has been a technical error which caused a wrong number be registered. (It was a different number that I realized as wrong and removed, but it seems it somehow got stuck in the system.) This is the basic ticket, non-modifiable and non-refundable.

I tried to call their customer service, but they did not pick up so far. How likely is this to cause an issue, if other details (such as my name) are correct, and I can prove that I was the one who paid for the ticket?

Comment: I answered a similar question before https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64636/passport-number-for-train-reservation-in-spain/64683#64683 and I would guess that it will be fine for you too, but my experience is now more out of date, so I'll wait until someone gives you a more definite answer.

Comment: Did you use your ticket? If so can you post an answer with what happened?